# Postgres 9.3 gives ERROR: Array values must start with ... for hex bytea value

Tags: postgresql, bytea

Given a simple table:

```
PGresult   *res  = PQexec(usersconn, "CREATE TABLE userfiles (username
 varchar[100] PRIMARY KEY, mydata bytea);");
```

I try to add a data with this:

```
    PGresult   *res = PQexec(usersconn, "INSERT into userfiles VALUES ( 
'peter' , '\\\\x1A' );" );
```

or this:

```
PGresult   *res = PQexec(usersconn, "INSERT into userfiles VALUES ( 'peter' , '\x1A' );" );
```

and I get an error message about array values must start with ...

What am I doing wrong in trying to insert a simple hex constant into this record?

Answer (score 0):

Hex values have to use escape syntax:

```
INSERT into userfiles VALUES ( 'peter' , e'\\x1A' );
```

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-binary.html

Comment: That should have been the answer. But... doing that still gives the same error.

Comment: using PGresult   *res = PQexec(usersconn, "INSERT into userfiles VALUES ( 'peter' , E'\\\\000'  );" );   gives the same error

Comment: I get the same message when I make the field type "text" and use this insert: "INSERT into userfiles VALUES ( 'peter' , '1A'  );" );

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't the `bytea` field, it's the `username` field.

`varchar[100]` is an array of `100` varchar elements, each of which is of unbounded length.

I think you probably meant `varchar(100)`, a single `varchar` scalar of length 0-100.

Comment: yes. Both were problems, but only the first was being reported.